# How much cover do non-Medium tower shields provide?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, creature-size, shield, cover

Per the [tower shield](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/shield-tower/) description, it's possible to deploy a tower shield to effectively create a wall along one edge of your space. This makes sense for Medium creatures wielding Medium tower shields, as they only take up one space. However, a Large creature takes up four spaces, and a Large tower shield is presumably sized appropriately. Would such a shield provide cover along one full edge of the 2x2 square?

Note that this is not about [creatures using smaller tower shields for cover](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120491/13529).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, the tower shield would cover the entire 10 ft edge.** Space, as the term is used in the tower shield's description, does not refer to a 5x5 ft area ("square" is the appropriate term for such an area). Instead, "space" refers to the total area taken up by a creature (for example, see the "space" column in the [creature size table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary/#Size)). As a result, providing cover along one edge of a large creature's *space* would extend across the full 10 feet of that edge.